# Retrofit OkHttp A connection to xxx was leaked

Tags: android, connection, retrofit, okhttp

I got this warning when I used **Retrofit**, I find many answers on from stackoverflow. But many of them are talking about **OkHttp**.

I didn't do anything with the response body when I used Retrofit, I didn't find any method in retrofit.

Here's my custom OkHttpClient:

```
private OkHttpClient getOkHttpClient(){
  OkHttpClient.Builder builder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
  builder.connectTimeout(DEFAULT_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  builder.writeTimeout(DEFAULT_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  builder.readTimeout(DEFAULT_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  builder.addInterceptor(new ZCommonIntercepter());
  return builder.build();
}
```

I do have a custom interceptor, but I don't think that's the reason for this warning.

here's my interceptor, just add a header to keep the session with the server

```
Override
public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
  Response originalResponse = chain.proceed(chain.request());
  if (!isFirst) {
     if (!originalResponse.headers("Set-Cookie").isEmpty()) {
       ConstantPool.SESSION_HIDUI = originalResponse.header("Set-Cookie");
     }
  }

  isFirst = true;
  Request request = chain.request()
                .newBuilder()
                .removeHeader("Cookie")
                .addHeader("Cookie", ConstantPool.SESSION_HIDUI)
                .build();

  return chain.proceed(request);
}
```

I wanna know what's the reason cause the problem, didn't the retrofit2 do the response body. close for me?

and If I ignore this warning, is there something bad gonna happen? wrong about that.

Comment: show your log with exception

Comment: 11-11 09:47:57.936 1412-1412/? W/ContextImpl: Calling a method in the system process without a qualified user: android.app.ContextImpl.sendBroadcast:1053 com.android.server.am.OppoActivityStackHelper.sendIsHomeModeIntent:65 com.android.server.am.OppoActivityStackHelper.handleSendHomeMode:92 com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.resumeTopActivityLocked:1561 
11-11 09:47:58.536 4462-4496/? W/okhttp3.OkHttpClient: A connection to http://xxx.xxx.xx.xx/ was leaked. Did you forget to close a response body?

Comment: just Aconnection to xxx.xxx.xx.xx was leaked .did you forget to close a response body...

Answer (score 0):

The `originalResponse` in your interceptor hasn't been closed.